# How can I get the choose data (such as foreign data) like the RestFramework browser?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

How can I get the choose data (such as foreign data) like the RestFramework browser?

As all we know, if I have a model:

```
class Disk(models.Model):
    diskEssenceType = models.ForeignKey(to=DiskEssenceType, related_name='disks')  #  "SAS", "SSD"  
    diskOsType = models.ForeignKey(to=DiskOSType, related_name='disks') #  
    hostType = models.ForeignKey(to=HostType, related_name='disks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)  # price
```

There are three foreign fields.

In the serializers:

```
class DiskCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Disk
        fields = "__all__"
```

And the views.py:

```
class DiskCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DiskCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = Disk.objects.all()
```

When I access this create link:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see, there are serial optional drop-down boxes we can choose to add in my Disk instance creation.

So, how can we do this like in our custom website html so easily?

Or whether rest framework have return the drop-down boxes data, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> So, how can we do this like in our custom website html so easily?

This used to be possible by making an OPTION request on the resource. This [pull request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/4021) removed it.

So it's down to:

- either write your own metadata class to reintroduce it
- either add another endpoint that lists all the associated data